# a small web app to submit parameters to url from xls file

Tags: forms, web-services

I have a web service, that its URL structure is http://api.mywebservice.com/submit?name=&phone=& (recieves in GET method only)

what I'd like to do is import an xls/csv file with 2 columns,

A - name
B - phone

and execute an action that sends the values inside the defined parameters

example

if 1st row in the file is :

Johnny | 12345678

the app will execute: http://api.mywebservice.com/submit?name=Johnny&phone=12345678

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this on a Windows computer, then you use Powershell (which is either already installed on your computer or can be installed free of charge) to do this.  The script can loop through the records in the XLS file, and for each record construct the URL (using the values from the record), and do an HTTP GET request to the URL.

For information on how to use Powershell to loop through the records in an XLS file, see http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/09/11/how-can-i-read-from-excel-without-using-excel.aspx.

For information on how to use Powershell to do an HTTP GET request to a URL (using the System.Net.HttpWebRequest object), see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9c4849a3-4f82-4bbf-8415-b9a9ca13aacc/systemnethttpwebrequest.

Comment: sorry this is not helping me /=

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I'm looking for a simple script that'll execute a URL replacing the values of 2 strings - taken from a file. that's all.